# Apache mod_rewrite and RewriteMap usage

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, rewritemap

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap name2id txt:/path/to/map.txt

RewriteRule ^/mods/([^/]+)\.html$ /mod.php?id=${name2id:$1|0} [QSA,L]
```

First time to make a URL rewriting with rewriteMap. I have a code above but it returns a 404 page if i run `http://example.com/mysite/mods/abc.html` in my browser. I've put the above code in my virtual host file in apache configuration, I read in some forums that rewriteMap only works if you have access in *httpd.conf* and virtual host. mod_rewrite is running on my windows machine because I was able to run some rule defined in my .htaccess file.

The *map.txt* contains

```
abc 123
def 456
ghi 789
```

Comment: Did you make sure mod_rewrite is running properly and Apache allows .htaccess files?

Comment: Yes, mod_rewrite is properly running and allow .htaccess file. I was able to run some rules defined in htaccess.

Answer (score 1):

If you request `/mysite/mods/…`, your rule should rather be:

```
RewriteRule ^/mysite/mods/([^/]+)\.html$ /mod.php?id=${name2id:$1|0} [QSA,L]
```

Comment: but i declare my RewriteBase as /mysite. And even i add /mysite/mods/ still 404 is showing.. Is that okay if my rule is located in my htaccess file and the declaration of rewriteMap is in my virtual host?

Comment: Have you tried starting the rule with *^mods* instead of *^/mods*?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using RewriteBase, try removing the initial slash in the rule:

```
RewriteRule ^mods/([^/]+)\.html$ /mod.php?id=${name2id:$1|0} [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I got my code working, but when i run http://example.com/mysite/mods/abc.html I got 0 when i echoed the query string id, is that rigth? correct me if I'm wrong because i am expecting the equivalent of abc w/c is 123 will be displayed.